# Seamless listening from iPhone to iMac?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, data-synchronization

Is there any way to synchronise music playback position between iOS and OS X, so that I can go from listening to a song on my iPhone, then continue listening to it at the same place on my computer when I open it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. By using iPhone app called [Seamless](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/seamless/id420768433).